# CSS - place scrollbar in padding

Tags: html, css

I have a problem and i don't know how to solve it.

A div-container with a specific height has a padding on the right side. I want the scrollbar to show up in the padding-space of this container if the content of the container is too large.

**HTML**

```
<div class="top-content">
  <div class="inner-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-content">
  <div class="inner-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
    nascetur ridiculus mus. 
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top-content {
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;        
  }
  .inner-content {
    border-right: 1px solid #DDD;       
  }     
  .bottom-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .bottom-content > .inner-content {
    min-height: 100px;
  }
```

See this JsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ushLprzd/1/

I want the second example look like the first one, but with a scroll bar. Does anyone know a solution for this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Im looking to accomplish exactly this, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

just remove the text-aling: justify; and padding-right:20px;

or

give margin-right:-20px; to inner-content

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Could you show it in the JsFiddle?